# How to use useState() throughout multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, use-state

My first page looks something like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export const addItem = (ID, Name, Price, Img, Quantity, Color) => {
  setCartItems(ID, Name, Price, Img, Quantity, Color) // <-- this is the thing
}

function Navigation () {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  ...
}

export default Navigation;
```

On the second page I have a button which when pressed, would call the first page's `addItem` function. The problem is (I have pointed to it in the code) that I can't call the `setCartItems` function from outside the Navigation function. Is there any solution to this problem, I don't mind it being something different from `useState()` as long as it works. I am using react-router for the pages if that helps.

Comment: This won't work. `setCartItems` is undefined in `addItem`. If you want to share state then either [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or use a React [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). This isn't anything related to `react-router` BTW. I suggest creating and using a Context. Do you need assistance with an implementation like this?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you, I will check out React Context and tell you how it went.